# Push command line arguments (C) on the call stack?

Tags: command-line, parameters, callstack

I'm wondering how parameter passing for command line arguments works? My assembly is a little bit rusty. I understand that a function's parameters are pushed onto the stack by its caller. What about command line arguments? How are they pushed onto the stack frame of the main function?

Thanks

Comment: I learned all about this last year but it didn't quite stick.  I did however learn that you can go places by writing simple functions and running them through g++ with the -S flag, which produces assembly code as output.

Comment: No search engines where you are?

Comment: googled..but only found answers regarding regular arguments, not command-line arguments..

Answer (score 0):

In standard C, `main` can take at least two args -- the first being the number of command-line args, and the second being an array of pointers to them.  The order they appear on the stack is implementation-defined, but a common convention for C is to push them from right to left, so subsequent args appear at higher addresses.

As far as raw assembly is concerned, though...like most things assembly-related, it's platform dependent.  Linux parses command-line args for you and passes pointers to them on the stack.  In Windows, the command line is retrieved by a call into the OS (`GetCommandLineA` or `GetCommandLineW`), and you parse it yourself.   If you're using C or C++ with a Windows app, the command line is also one of the args to `WinMain`.

Comment: @user1640669: Again, it depends on the platform.  Since you have yet to even mention anything about your particular environment, i can't say with any certainty what it does.  Linux apparently does (at least to some degree); Windows doesn't.  Others, i don't know.  That's all i can say til you come up off some more info.  :P